# Long XAML parsing time at startup

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I am attempting to build a program to help with my medical charting. It was all going fine and debugging only took 3-4 seconds to launch. Today when I went to work on it it took a **full minute** to launch debugging. This seems unreasonably long with this uncomplicated code. I ran the Performance Profiler and it looks like most of the time is spent on parsing of the MainWindow. [Pic of Performace Profiler.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhY3p.jpg)
There is also another window that opens from a context menu option within the program, it used to open instantly, but now it takes a good 10 seconds to open.

Am I doing something wrong here?

XAML code -

```
<Window x:Name="Form1" x:Class="ChiroHelp_3._1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=system"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChiroHelp_3._1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ChiroHelp 3.1" Height="970" Width="1338" MinHeight="970" MinWidth="1200" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="TabControlSOAP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="923" Margin="5,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="822">
        <TabItem x:Name="TabSubjective" Header="Subjective">
            <Grid Background="#FFFFFFFF">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="898" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="822" Margin="-3,0,-3,-1">
                    <TabItem x:Name="TabHPI" Header="HPI">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBox x:Name="textBoxSubAddyo" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="52" Margin="10,10,785,840"/>
                            <Label Content="year old" Margin="35,10,728,840" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Padding="1"/>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxSubAddyoM" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="88,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Padding="4,1,1,1">
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="male "/>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="female "/>
                            </ComboBox>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxSubAddyoP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="157,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Padding="4,1,1,1">
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="PTC "/>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="RTC "/>
                            </ComboBox>
                            <Label Content="for" Margin="226,10,571,840" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Padding="1"/>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxSubAddyoE" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="250,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="197" Padding="4,1,1,1">
                                <ComboBoxItem Content=""/>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="evaluation and management of "/>
                            </ComboBox>
                            <Button x:Name="SubAddyo" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="452,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56" Click="SubAddyo_Click" Focusable="False"/>
                            <Button Content="LOCQSMAT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="10,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78"/>
                            <Button Content="Thyroid Symptoms:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="10,113,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="118"/>
                            <Button Content="Diabetes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="10,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="56"/>
                            <Label Content="year old" Margin="13,39,750,811" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Padding="1"/>
                            <Label Content="year old" Margin="13,89,750,761" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Padding="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem x:Name="TabROS" Header="ROS"/>
                </TabControl>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="TabObjective" Header="Objective">
            <Grid Background="#FFFFFFFF">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="898" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="822" Margin="-3,0">
                    <TabItem x:Name="TabMusculoskeletal" Header="Musculoskeletal">
                        <Grid Background="#FFFFFFFF">
                            <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="871" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="822" Margin="-3,1,-3,-1">
                                <TabItem x:Name="TabJtPalpation" Header="Jt Palpation"/>
                                <TabItem x:Name="TabMslPalpation" Header="Msl Palpation"/>
                                <TabItem x:Name="TabCx" Header="Cx Exam"/>
                                <TabItem x:Name="TabTx" Header="Tx Exam"/>
                                <TabItem x:Name="TabLx" Header="Lx/SI Exam"/>
                                <TabItem x:Name="TabHA" Header="HA Exam"/>
                                <TabItem x:Name="TabShoulder" Header="Shoulder Exam"/>
                                <TabItem x:Name="TabKnee" Header="Knee Exam"/>
                            </TabControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem x:Name="TabOther" Header="Other"/>
                </TabControl>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="TabAssessment" Header="Assessment"/>
        <TabItem x:Name="TabPlan" Header="Plan"/>
    </TabControl>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBoxSoapPreview" Margin="832,27,8,61" AcceptsTab="True" AcceptsReturn="True" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="11" UndoLimit="1000" ContextMenuOpening="SOAPContextMenuOpening" TextChanged="RichTextBoxSoapPreview_TextChanged" SelectionChanged="RichTextBoxSoapPreview_SelectionChanged" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True">
        <SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
            <sys:Uri>pack://application:,,,/MedDic.lex</sys:Uri>
        </SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
        <RichTextBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
            </ContextMenu>
        </RichTextBox.ContextMenu>
        <RichTextBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </RichTextBox.Resources>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Subjective:"/>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph/>
            <Paragraph/>
            <Paragraph>
                <InlineUIContainer x:Name="ROSContainer">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockROS" Background="LightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:DesignUseLayoutRounding="True" ><Run Text="@ROS@"/></TextBlock>
                </InlineUIContainer>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph/>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Objective:"/>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <InlineUIContainer x:Name="ObjectiveContainer">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockObjective" Background="LightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:DesignUseLayoutRounding="True"><Run Text="@Objective@"/></TextBlock>
                </InlineUIContainer>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph/>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Assessment:"/>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <InlineUIContainer x:Name="AssessmentContainer">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlockAssessment" Background="LightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" UseLayoutRounding="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:DesignUseLayoutRounding="True"><Run Text="@Assessment@"/></TextBlock>
                </InlineUIContainer>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph/>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Plan:"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="832,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="488">
        <ToggleButton x:Name = "ToggleButtonBold" Content = "B" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=RichTextBoxSoapPreview}" Margin = "0,0,465,0" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <ToggleButton x:Name = "ToggleButtonItalic" Content = "I" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleItalic" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=RichTextBoxSoapPreview}" Margin = "28,0,437,0" FontStyle="Italic" />
        <ToggleButton x:Name = "ToggleButtonUnderline" Content = "U" Command="EditingCommands.ToggleUnderline" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=RichTextBoxSoapPreview}" Margin = "56,0,409,0" />
        <Button x:Name="ButtonInsertROS" Content="ROS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="ButtonInsertROS_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonInsertObjective" Content="Objective" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,0,0,0" Width="75" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="ButtonInsertObjective_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="ButtonInsertAssessment" Content="Assessment" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="290,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="ButtonInsertAssessment_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Update - I went through the XAML code commenting and uncommenting sections. It looks like the problem is with the...

```
<SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
        <sys:Uri>pack://application:,,,/MedDic.lex</sys:Uri>
    </SpellCheck.CustomDictionaries>
```

When I comment this section it loads in 107ms, when I uncomment this section it takes 52 seconds. The MedDic.lex file I have is a medical dictionary that is quite large. I removed all but two words in the dictionary and the problem persists.

Am I adding a custom dictionary correctly? Why is this taking so long to parse?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem once, for me restarting Visual Studio solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm still having the same problem, even restarting the computer didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

Performing a `Clean Solution

Closing the solution file and Visual Studio

Delete the bin and obj directories

Delete .vs directory

Try debugging again

Comment: Ok, I did a Clean Solution, closed the file, and deleted the directories. When I debugged again it did take about 7 seconds off, but its still at 52 seconds startup.

Comment: Why do you think it's slow?  What spec machine have you got?  What's it like without a debugger attached?

Comment: I have an HP Pavilion with an i7-7700 processor, 12GB RAM, and a 1TB hard drive. I am running Windows 10. When I just run the .exe file without the debugger it is still slow. See my update - it is an issue with adding a custom dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code was fine. I tried it on another computer and it worked as expected. I reinstalled windows on my computer and things were back to normal. Still not sure what was going on, but that fixed it.